# jQuery making a loop of functions, each with an animate queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, hide, show

So this is a bit of a head scratcher and I've resorted to asking for help with it. I have created a series of functions with jQuery. Each function contains an animate() queue and ends with a call back that loads the next function, again with it's own animate() queue. Once it reaches the end it calls the first function again and around we go. I have separated the queues into independent functions, because I want to be able to jump to specific points in the loop based on user clicks. So in the code below the loop runs through once, but when it goes back to the beginning the show() and hide() bits don't appear to be doing anything. Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

```
var firstItem = jQuery('#vehicle-banner-one');
var firstThumb = jQuery('#thumb-one');
var secondItem = jQuery('#vehicle-banner-two');
var secondThumb = jQuery('#thumb-two');
var thirdItem = jQuery('#vehicle-banner-three');
var thirdThumb = jQuery('#thumb-three');
var nextItem = firstItem;
var nextThumb = firstThumb;

firstItem.hide();
secondItem.hide();
thirdItem.hide();

function leadIn(){
    console.log('leadIn');
    thirdItem.css({zIndex:8});
    secondItem.css({zIndex:9});
    firstItem.css({zIndex:10});

    firstItem.fadeIn("slow", function(){ holdOne(); });
}



function holdOne(){
    console.log('holdOne'); 
    thirdItem.css({zIndex:8}).hide();
    secondItem.css({zIndex:9}).hide();
    firstItem.css({zIndex:10}).show();

    firstItem.delay(3000).delay(0, function(){ transTwo(); });
};

function transTwo(){
    console.log('transTwo'); 
    thirdItem.css({zIndex:8}).hide();
    secondItem.css({zIndex:10}).hide();
    firstItem.css({zIndex:9}).show();

    secondItem.fadeIn("slow" , function(){ holdTwo(); });
};

function holdTwo(){
    console.log('holdTwo'); 
    thirdItem.css({zIndex:8}).hide();
    secondItem.css({zIndex:10}).show();
    firstItem.css({zIndex:9}).hide();

    secondItem.delay(3000).delay(0, function(){ transThree(); });
};

function transThree(){
   console.log('transThree'); 
    thirdItem.css({zIndex:10}).hide();
    secondItem.css({zIndex:9}).show();
    firstItem.css({zIndex:8}).hide();

    thirdItem.fadeIn("slow" , function(){ holdThree(); });
};

function holdThree(){
    console.log('holdThree'); 
    thirdItem.css({zIndex:10}).show();
    secondItem.css({zIndex:9}).hide();
    firstItem.css({zIndex:8}).hide();

    thirdItem.delay(3000).delay(0, function(){ transOne(); });
};


function transOne(){
    console.log('transOne'); 
    thirdItem.css({zIndex:9}).show();
    secondItem.css({zIndex:8}).hide();
    firstItem.css({zIndex:10}).hide();

    firstItem.fadeIn("slow" , function(){ holdOne(); });
};

leadIn();



///toggle by clicking thumbnails

jQuery('#thumb-one').on('click', function(){console.log('1'); holdOne();});
jQuery('#thumb-two').on('click', function(){console.log('2'); holdTwo();});
jQuery('#thumb-three').on('click', function(){console.log('3'); holdThree();});

});
```

Comment: Note: You don't need all the anonymous functions on the callbacks that call a single function... Just pass the function names: e.g. `firstItem.delay(3000).delay(0, transTwo);`

Answer (score 0):

looks kinda complicated... all i understood was, that you are looking for a way to loop through a list of items AND interrupt the loop any time with a click and then start from there on...

i've needed something similar some time before... we start with the snippet from [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/)
All he does, is using the setInterval function to cycle through the elements:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

this is neat and nice. it shows the first element, fades it out, takes the next element, fades it in and finally appends the first element to the end of the list.
this means, that the visible element is always the first one and therefore good to address.

that was it from css-tricks ... now we are out on our own, and we do want to have a link list, to directly address the single slides... i choose to enumerate all my pages, so this was my solution:

```
for (i = 1; i <= $("#slides div").length; i++) {
    var slideName = $("#slides div").eq(i - 1).attr("name");
    $("#slideselect").append("<a href='#' class='singleSelect' name='" + slideName + "'>" + i + " </a>");
}
```

having a link-list, won't help, as long as you don't have a click function. since the links are inserted after document.ready, i had to use on("click", , function), to have the click handle available...
the function first of all finds the name of the clicked element and compares it to the current active element. in case they match, we won't do anything, since the clicked slide is already shown.

```
$("#slideselect").on("click", ".singleSelect", function () {
    var clickedSlide = $(this).attr("name");
    var activeSlide = $('#slides > .activeSlide').attr("name");
    clearInterval(cycleHandle);
    if (clickedSlide != activeSlide) {
```

then, because we don't want to destroy our ordered list, we loop through our elements always moving the first one to the last position, until we found our clicked element. afterwards, we fadeout the active slide and fade in the clicked one...

```
        while (clickedSlide != $('#slides > div:first').attr("name")) {
            $('#slides > div:first').appendTo('#slides');
        }

        $('#slides > .activeSlide').fadeOut(1000)
            .removeClass("activeSlide").end();
        $('#slides > div:first').fadeIn(1000)
            .addClass("activeSlide")
            .end();
    }
    cycleHandle = setInterval(function(){myCycle()}, 3000);
});
```

the code inside my post is already the finished version. what you may notice is the clearInterval and setInterval call... if you won't clear the interval, the clicked slide will correct fade in to display, but the interval keeps running with the old offset. e.g. if you click a page 1 sec before the interval-loop would move on, your clicked slide will be there for only 1sec...
so i took the css-trick snippet into my own cycle function, and call this once after document ready. and inside the click handle, you'll stop the interval and start it again...

well hope you understood my work... here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sx1mozeg/2/

there is still strange behaviour with the transitions, if you spam your clicks... need to improve that ...

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your detailed response. I will take some time to review your answer carefully. I had the feeling that my solution was kinda klunky!

Comment: since i only had your js and no html and css, i've met a lot of assumptions to what your question really is... and i hope, it was a good guess^^
but you have for sure to rework your html also, to get this to work.
inside the div's, you could also use <img> or something else... 
but i made the experience, that you can't use complex structures inside the slide-divs - don't know why - just wouldn't work... but maybe it's due to an old jquery version... i'll retry it after my holidays...